# Conditional formatting comparing numbers and words

Tags: conditional-formatting

I want to apply conditional formatting to cell h26 based on its comparison to cell d26. However, cell a1 can only be filled in with "true" or "false" while cell b1 can only be filled in with 1 or 0.

How can I get the formatting to understand that 1 = 'true' and that 0 = 'false'?

I want cell h26 to be highlighted only in cases where the values between both cells aren't the same. E.g. cell d26 =1 and cell h26 = "false".

This is the code that I currently have:

```
=OR(AND($D$26="TRUE",$H$26=0),AND($D$26="FALSE",$H$26=1))
```

The goal is for cell `h26` to highlight if `d26 = "TRUE"` while `h26=0` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about
[Using logical functions in Excel: AND, OR, XOR and NOT](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-and-or-xor-not-functions/).

In this simple case, you don't have to convert anything, just to
write the right formula for the two conditions.

Some untested code would be:

```
=OR(AND($A1=1, $B1), AND($A1=0, NOT($B1)))
```

Making this code work in your spreadsheet is up to you.